# Uniqueness of Compound Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X =^d \sum_{i=1}^N Y_i$ where $N$ is Poisson and $(Y_i)$ is a sequence of IID random variables independent of $N$. Then $X$ is said to have a compound Poisson distribution. Now if $X_1 = \sum_{i=1}^N Y_i$ and $X_2 = \sum_{i=1}^M Z_i$ are compound Poisson and $X_1 =^d X_2$, where $N \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_N)$, $M \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_M)$ with $P(Y_i=0) = P(Z_i=0)=0$, how can I show that $\lambda_N = \lambda_M$ and $Y_i =^d Z_i$?

The characteristic function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $$\phi_1(t) = \exp[-\lambda_N(1-\phi_Y(t))], \quad \phi_2(t) = \exp[-\lambda_M(1-\phi_Z(t))]$$ respectively. We know that $\phi_1 = \phi_2$. How can I show that $\lambda_N = \lambda_M$ and $\phi_Y = \phi_Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to note that since $-\ln \phi_1(t)=-\ln\phi_2(t)$ you obtain

$$\lambda_N(1-\phi_Y(t))=\lambda_M(1-\phi_Z(t))$$

Inverse-Fourier transforming this equality gives a relation between the pdfs of $Y,Z$, $f_Y(x), f_Z(x)$:

$$(\lambda_N-\lambda_M)\delta(x)=\lambda_Nf_Y(x)-\lambda_M f_Z(x)$$

Integrate this to obtain a relationship between the cdf's

$$(\lambda_N-\lambda_M)\theta(x)=\lambda_NF_Y(x)-\lambda_MF_Z(x)$$

Since there is no point mass at the origin we have that $F_{Y,Z}(0^-)=F_{Y,Z}(0^+)$, so taking left and right limits around $x=0$ forces $\lambda_N=\lambda_M$, as it is easy to see. The equality of probability distributions follows trivially thereafter.

**EDIT:** In case the pdf of $Y,Z$ are not defined it is still possible to prove uniqueness. First, note that any random variable has a CDF, by definition. From well known theorems, it is seen that

1. Any single variable function that obeys the CDF axioms is right continuous everywhere on the real line (*ref: Kun Il Park, Fundamentals of Probability and Stochastic Processes with Applications to Communications, p.79*)
2. Any single variable function that is right continuous everywhere can be shown to be discontinuous only on a countable subset $B$ of the reals, [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148866/is-there-a-function-defined-on-real-numbers-which-is-continuous-from-the-left-b)

In light of these results, the following inversion formula gives the unique CDF assigned to a characteristic function

$$2F_X(x)-1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ixt}\phi_X(-t)-e^{-ixt}\phi_X(t)}{it}dt$$

and the integral on the RHS converges on $x\in B^c$.

Assuming $\phi_1(t)=\phi_2(t)$ yields the family of solutions

\begin{equation}\lambda_N-\lambda_M+2n\pi i=\lambda_N \phi_Y(t)-\lambda_M\phi_Z(t),~~ n\in \mathbb{Z}\tag{1}\end{equation}

Forming the linear combination  $(it)^{-1}(e^{itx}(1)(-t)-e^{-itx}(1)(t))$ and integrating yields after some rearrangement the relation

$$\lambda_N F_Y(x)-\lambda_M F_Z(x)=(\lambda_N-\lambda_M)\theta(x)+n\pi i ~\text{sgn}(x)~~, x\in B^c$$

Obviously, since the LHS is purely real, this forces $n=0$. From this point on, one can use the argument presented pre-edit to conclude that $\lambda_N=\lambda_M~,~ F_Y(x)=F_Z(x) ~, ~x\in B^c$, and the right continuity to conclude that the jumps are also fixed to be the same, which implies that $F_Y(x)=F_Z(x) ~~,~ x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: An observation: OP hasn't assumed there are densities neither for $Y$ nor $Z$.

Comment: Indeed, $Y$ and $Z$ might not have densities. In addition, since $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are complex numbers and complex log is a multivalued function, can we simply take logarithms on both sides?

Comment: @Snoop Fair criticism, edited with a proof that does involve passing through the pdf to prove the statement, in exchange for a slightly more technical argument.